# Sort an arraylist by an object's attribute or method *but by different sort orders = ABC, BCA, CAB, etc

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a list which contains items which have a variable which contains which may be *1 of 3 different values*. 
I want to be able to sort the list according to the value given so that the list will end up as: `[b,b,b, c,c,c, a,a,a]` or any pattern of my choosing.
(where b, c, or a is a representation of *itemType* of MyItem see code below.)

The sorted list would end up as [MyItem, MyItem, MyItem ...and so on] just sorted so that MyItem with itemType = b comes first, then with type c comes second, then with type a comes third.

Maybe a better way to describe what I want is *grouping* or sorting in groups?

```
public class MyItem {
    // possible values for item type
    public static final int ITEM_TYPE_A = 0x0;
    public static final int ITEM_TYPE_B = 0x1;
    public static final int ITEM_TYPE_C = 0x2;

    protected int itemType; 
}

public class ArrayThing {
    ArrayList<MyItem> list;

    public void sortBy(int sortOrder) {
        /* sort items in list by sortOrder takes a 3 digit int     
           representing the order examples: 123 = ABC, 321 = CBA
        */ 
        switch(sortOrder) {
            case(123): do sort stuff here // sort by order ABC
            case(132): do sort stuff here // sort by order ACB
            case(231): do sort stuff here // sort by order BCA
            /* and so on */
}
```

How can I easily do this?

Hopefully this explains what I want to do pretty clearly. If not I'm more than willing to clarify :)

Comment: Implement a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for each sort order and use [`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: This should not be marked as a duplicate (or at least a better duplicate should be found). This can be done in `O(n)` time whereas using a `Comparator` and `List.sort` or `Collections.sort` will only do it in `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Reopened as the OP does not ask about comparators, and there are simpler approaches first dividing the items into 3 separate groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done more efficiently than using `Comparator`s by taking advantage of the fact that there are only 3 possible items. It is in my opinion also slightly easier to program. Here is an example of how you could write it (not tested).

```
public void sortBy(int sortOrder) {
    // Step 1: Divide the items into 3 groups
    List<List<MyItem>> groups = Arrays.asList(new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>());
    for (MyItem item : list)
        groups.get(item.itemType).add(item);

    // Step 2: Use a string to represent the order (ugly, but works)
    String order = String.valueOf(sortOrder);

    // Step 3: Put the three groups back into the list in the correct order.
    int index = 0;
    for (char c : order.toCharArray())
        for (MyItem item : groups.get(c - '1'))
            list.set(index++, item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a custom sort compare function to achieve what you are looking for.

```
class SortItem implements Comparator<MyItem>
{
    public int compare(MyItem a, MyItem b)
    {
          // your logic to sort the items based on a.itemType and b.itemType
          // return int negative value will push item b before a and value 0 and above leaves both the item unchanged.
    }
}
```

Then you could sort your array like

```
ArrayThing arr = [.......]; // your ArrayThing Object
Arrays.sort(arr, new SortItem());
```

Now you arr should be sorted based on custom criteria. Hope this helps.